# mobwrite issue - daemon wont start

Tags: php, python, linux, unix, daemon

I installed http://code.google.com/p/google-mobwrite/wiki/Daemon MobWrite, but when I try to run it the daemon wouldn't start and it returns the following: (any suggestions?)

```
  root@mobs:~/mobwrite/daemon# python2.4 mobwrite_daemon.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "mobwrite_daemon.py", line 728, in ?
        main()
      File "mobwrite_daemon.py", line 703, in main
        mobwrite_core.CFG.initConfig(ROOT_DIR + "lib/mobwrite_config.txt")
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CFG'
    root@mobs:~/mobwrite/daemon# nohup python2.4 mobwrite_daemon.py
    nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
    root@mobs:~/mobwrite/daemon# ps waux |grep mobwrite
    root      1202  0.0  0.2   6156   668 pts/0    S+   18:35   0:00 grep --color=au                                to mobwrite
```

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the directory you uncompressed, for me it is called mobwrite_daemon.  You will then need to copy the directory lib and all of its contents to the directory where you are running the daemon from.  That will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

At the date of June 16 2014, when you download the zip file you will have the following arcitecture inside:

```
mobwrite_daemon
    daemon  => (data, lib)    // "A" lib folder
    demos
    html
    tests
    lib                    // "B" lib folder
    ...
```

To run the daemon and avoid the  `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CFG'` error, you need to replace the "A" lib folder by the "B" lib folder.